# Enabling GSMA in Azure Kubernetes Service

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-aks

I have setup a Kubernetes Cluster using aks-engine to deploy a kubernetes configuration enabling feature-gates([github aks-engine](https://github.com/azure/aks-engine)) in this case `--feature-gates=WindowsGMSA=true`. 
The installation is successful, the cluster is created with 2 nodes(windows agent, linux master) now i am trying to domain join and create GSMA to enable Authentication. 
I am unclear on the process as i am new in AKS and Azure/Active Directory. Any help would be appreciated.

I created an AD DS in Azure and tried to domain joined to the windows node and it is not working, maybe i am doing this wrong.

Comment: The aks-engine is not the same as the AKS. If you use the AKS, you can take a look at [Control access to cluster resources using role-based access control and Azure Active Directory identities in Azure Kubernetes Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us//azure/aks/azure-ad-rbac).

Comment: Hi @CharlesXu , well i am using aks-engine to enable Integrated Windows Authentication using the WindowsGMSA feature gate which seemed feasible. Can i do that with the link provided?

Comment: As I know, AKS does not support the GMSA currently. You can use the Azure Active Directory identity with it.

Comment: @CharlesXu True the managed version Azure Kubernetes Service , but aks-engine in which you can enable these features does. Maybe i need to clarify in my question.